# Exporting a full WhatsApp chat to .txt

Tags: backup, export, whatsapp-messenger

So, I've decided to try and do some analysis on my WhatsApp chat history. For that purpose, the built-in export function would work quite well, **but** it is for some reason restricted to the latest 40.000 messages. Some of my chats go back way further than that, and I'd like to include those conversations in my dataset.

And that's where it gets complicated. Things I've tried so far:

1. A variety of recovery tools (drfone, BackupToolForWhatsApp,...) that invariably failed to connect and/or demanded a lot of money and/or contained malware
2. Finding the msgstore.db.crypt12 as a file on the phone and opening it as text with various apps (some people claimed that worked, it didn't though, everything just crashed or complained about the format)
3. Copying the msgstore.db.crypt12 onto my computer and there decrypting it with the key file, which led to the next problem, obtaining said key file.
4. A bunch of outdated and thus no longer functional WhatsApp key extractor tools which tried to either grab the backups off Google Drive, or temporarily install a legacy Version of WhatsApp with a vulnerability that allowed the key to be extracted. This failed because the tools haven't been updated in like three years and I'm not Java-savy enough to go digging in their source code myself. I actually downloaded a legacy APK to try and manually install that old WhatsApp version, but that only led to an error about the datetime of my phone (which was set to automatic and thus was correct) and no key.
5. Rooting my phone in order to get access to the directory where the key is hopefully located. This failed, perhaps because I did the mistake of updating my firmware to the July 2019 patch level, and so no root exploits seemed to work
6. Digging around in protected directories with tools that do not quite require root access. However, I wasn't able to locate anything that even looked like the place WhatsApp might store its key.
7. Reading through lots of forum posts on the same issue without any discernible results.

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy S8, model number SM-G950F, German localization, with Android 9.

My question is simple: What else can I do? It can't be that it's literally impossible to dig at the messages which WhatsApp is happily storing and backing up. I'd even be willing to buy some software as long as it's reasonably priced and guaranteed to work.

Also, what directory would I be looking for to get that key, assuming I'd somehow get root access?

Update 28.07.2020:
It seems that in some locales (specifically the EU?), the native export function was disabled in its entirety. The method detailed in my answer below still works excellently, however.

Comment: How about exporting each contact for its own? Maybe 40.000 is sufficient. regarding 4. someone managed it on S10 with Pie 9.0 the pitfall is reboot required between uninstall (-k)/install. date can be set to past manually 5. should be possible in near future (assuming you already unlocked) With root access you don't need the key, there is unencrypted database too you can use. its all in /data/data/com.whatsapp

Comment: @alecxs Unfortunately, I had individual chats with significantly more than 40.000 messages. And I saw the forum post where someone managed to do it with Android 9, but following the same steps did not yield any results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, here's the solution I ended up using. Even though it's not ideal, it worked out, so I'll leave this here in case anyone else stumbles upon this.

The weak link in the chain is WhatsApp Web. Specifically, it's possible to write a tool that just scrapes the data WhatsApp Web receives, and someone on the Chrome Web Store did exactly that: The [Backup WhatsApp Chats](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/backup-whatsapp-chats/gmbicfpadlmgkfhfepknbmemfhahelll) extension. It's like €3, so well within what I'd consider reasonable. However, I'd expect that anyone with more knowledge of coding than I have could write such a script themselves, because the messages in WhatsApp Web are apparently just displayed as plain HTML.

It's reasonably fast and extracts all the non-media data you might want in csv format that can be parsed pretty well by pandas.

I'll accept my own answer because this is a solution within the parameters I set out, but if someone knows a better way, feel free to post it and I'll shift the accept.

Comment: Does this actually work with chats with millions of messages over several years though?

Comment: @Turkeyphant I've successfully done it with 391.000 messages stretching back to July 2015, so I at least have no reason to assume it would break at higher scales. The largest of those chats contained 128.095 messages, which took a few, but no more than twenty minutes to export fully.

Comment: Thanks. How long did that take? And do you see anything on the WhatApp Web screen while it scrapes?

Comment: @Turkeyphant In total it took me an hour for all the chats maybe, and while it scrapes, there's an overlay on the screen that says "Downloading messages" and displays a count of messages downloaded.

Comment: So you can't use WhatsApp Web at the same time?

Comment: @Turkeyphant Nope, I'm afraid with this method you have to wait for the program to finish exporting.

Comment: @Turkeyphant there's now an option to allow it to download in the background while you continue chatting!

Comment: As a quick update: As of October 25th 2021, the developers seem to be selling license codes for the extension through their own website at https://chatsaver.org/ , but if you previously bought the extension on the Chrome store, you can contact them to get a new license code. I don't know what the purpose of the move is (maybe trying not to pay a share to the Chrome store?), but for the moment, it still works.

Comment: It should also be noted that presumably this method will break if using the multi-device beta, as it no longer allows devices to go arbitrarily far into the past chat history.

Comment: Does this Chrome extension method somehow work for migrating to Telegram while maintaining media? That's my goal, I want to move all my family chats!

Comment: @ctrlbrk This method yields only chat transcripts, but I would not know how to migrate them to telegram. I believe, however, that downloading media is possible if you're just looking to preserve them, not have them appear in Telegram

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. I just tried to apply this to a probably 200k messages chat, spanning over 7 years. So I installed the recommended Chrome extension, bought the license key, launched the WhatsApp web app, opened the chat I am interested in, and then launched the extension. I selected the chat's timeframe, chose format .txt, and pushed 'download'. After a very short message of 'checking license key' then nothing. No spinning wheel, no nothing. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: In the meantime, I realized I was using a Whatsapp app for PC which did not launch from Chrome. I corrected that, the download started as it should have, but it downloaded much less than even the max 40 thousand messages, probably about 4000 only :( Tried several times choosing different formats (.txt, html etc.) - same result.